# Jenkins Add Python

Tags: python, jenkins, installation

I've noticed that Jenkins has support to automatically install versions of Ant, Groovy, or Maven on slaves. e.g. Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Groovy installations...

[image: Groovy Installations...]

Is there an equivalent for Python?

Comment: [did you try ShiningPanda Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin)

Comment: I was aware of it but did not think it supported Python installations... After investigating it does. But it seems very similar to a custom tool and expects a version of Python to come as a zip/tar.gz. Portable Python might meet that criteria but I believe that's Windows specific.